# Full Text Search not working on XML Columns on SQL Azure

Tags: sql-server, xml, azure, full-text-search, azure-sql-database

So SQL Azure recently released a new feature as part of the V12 Upgrades. You can now implement Full Text Search catalogs on your database.

http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2015/04/30/full-text-search-is-now-available-for-preview-in-azure-sql-database/

I've gone through the Setup instructions, and created an FTI pn a table with an XML Data column.

```
CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG recordDataCatalog AS DEFAULT;
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON RecordData(Data) KEY INDEX PK_RecordData ON recordDataCatalog; 
ALTER FULLTEXT INDEX ON RecordData ENABLE; 
GO 
ALTER FULLTEXT INDEX ON RecordData START FULL POPULATION;
```

Setup went fine; it's quite a big table (~0.5m rows) so I left it over night and came back the next day.

It looks like it's completed. But searching for known strings in the XML is returning no results.

```
SELECT * FROM RecordData WHERE Contains(Data, 'formsof(freetext, john)')
(0 row(s) affected)
SELECT * FROM RecordData WHERE Contains(Data, 'john')
(0 row(s) affected)
```

The `FULLTEXTCATALOGPROPERTY` for `PopulateStatus` is reporting it's Idle.

The row count for the table, is the same as the Item Count in the Catalog.

```
select count(id) from recorddata
------------------------------------------
(No column name)
539726
------------------------------------------
SELECT FULLTEXTCATALOGPROPERTY('recordDataCatalog','ItemCount')
----------------------------------------- 
(No column name)
539726
```

One strange thing I've noticed is that the index keywords seem to be missing/not populated properly.

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_fts_index_keywords(
    DB_ID('TransomTest'), 
    OBJECT_ID('RecordData'))
------------------------------------------------------
keyword display_term    column_id   document_count
0xFF    END OF FILE     2           539726
```

Anyone got any idea where to head next. Most of the SQL Docs regarding FTS & XML say that this should just work, and word lists should be parsed based on XML tag boundaries. Documentation specific to Azure is non-existant given how new this feature is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

xml document types indexing is not supported yet and there is work in progress to support this. The list of current document types supported can be queried using :

```
select * from sys.fulltext_document_types where version !=''
```

Comment: I'd have assumed document types was different from native sql column types though ? maybe not. strange that tehy explicitly said XML is supported in the first paragraph of the announce.

Is there an official source/comment on this or where did you find info that there is work in progrees. ?

Comment: I am from SQL Engineering team and working on this. You can also see the update in this blog: http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2015/04/30/full-text-search-is-now-available-for-preview-in-azure-sql-database/

Comment: This should be available in next couple weeks. Thanks!

Comment: This is available now.